# "cannot find the .txt file do you want to create a new file"

Tags: error

I'm not sure what happened.  I was running SharePoint Designer 2010 just fine until yesterday afternoon.  Yesterday I was trying to clean off my desktop and reorganize my folders.  I may have removed a file that was necessary.  I'm not sure.
Now I'm getting this error when I try to open a page from SharePoint through Site Actions> Edit in SharePoint Designer.
[image: Error]

Also, the Microsoft Designer download comes up.  I've tried to uninstall SP Designer, and reinstall it, but I'm still getting the same error.
If I select No in the dialogue box, it comes up again the next time.  If I select Yes, it opens the Notepad and saves it to my desktop.
I can still access the SharePoint sites when I open SharePoint designer from my computer, I just can't access the SharePoint Designer when I am in SharePoint and select "Edit in SharePoint Designer."  Any thoughts?  Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check In IE go to Tools > Internet Options > Programs and see if "Microsoft SharePoint Designer" is selected as the "HTML Editor".

Otherwise, i would repair /Unistall & reinstall the SharePoint designer and reboot the PC.

Comment: That worked!  Thank you!  Any idea what I might have done?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the notepad file from the Startup folder.

Comment: Notepad shortcut*